# WebSQL será mesmo descontinuado?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, websql, indexeddb

Estou com muitos problemas ao tentar executar em produção um programa desenvolvido em HTML 5, Javascript, Ajax, JSON, IndexedDB, MySQL, PHP, juntamente com a IDE Intel XDK.

O programa é bem simples ele captura informações do MySQL e persiste no IndexedDB, isto só funciona na emulação do Intel XDK, quando instalo ele no celular com Android 4.1.2 (API 16), não funciona, utilizo os *plugins* e mesmo assim não vai.

A questão é, este projeto tem somente uma tela um *button* para executar a sincronização e um `ListView`, e como é simples de momento se utilizar o WebSQL que funciona perfeitamente e ai amanha ou depois o **WebSQL será mesmo descontinuado ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atualmente esta tecnologia é considerada deprecada e não deve ser usada.

---

Ninguém pode afirmar quando e se uma tecnologia suportada atualmente por alguma plataforma será suportada no futuro. A história indica que até mesmo coisas certas deixaram de ser certas em algum momento. Faz parte do risco do desenvolver escolher uma tecnologia que poderá se tornar obsoleta e não suportada em futuras versões.

Especificamente esta tecnologia é mais arriscada. Ela não é considerada padrão, é suportada só em algumas plataformas de desenvolvimento web, é quase certo que não será suportada por outras. E sim, um dia ela poderá deixar de ser suportada nas plataformas atuais.

A falta de suporte de uma certa forma já ocorre. Não vejo isto sendo trabalhado onde é oficialmente suportado. Me parece já ser legado. Mas também não vejo que tão cedo seja retirado das plataformas que a suportam.

A opção é pelo IndexedDB. Se está tendo problemas com ele, tente saná-los. Desistir não parece ser a melhor opção.

Se estiver absolutamente certo que não há solução então pode usar alternativas. Idealmente seria interessante suportar as duas tecnologias, a padrão quando dá, e a alternativa quando for a única possibilidade.

[Suporte atual do WebSQL](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage).

[Suporte atual do IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Note que o AP faz uma pequena confusão entre `IndexedDB` e `WEBSQL`, ele dá a entender que está à usar `IndexedDB`, porém em alguns momentos o chama de `WEBSQL`.

Comment: Pode ser mesmo.

Comment: Desculpe amigos, explicando melhor:

Estou utilizando o IndexedDB mas ele não funciona, ai por este motivo criei este tópico para pedir mais informações em relação ao WEBSQL e ver se realmente compensa trabalhar com esta tecnologia e não ter problemas futuros.

Mas com todas as respostas,, me esclareceram, por isto estou sem duvidas, estou sem dúvidas - obrigado a todos

Answer (score 4):

Vejo que faz uma pequena confusão entre `IndexedDB` e `WebSQL`, a sua pergunta dá à entender que está à utilizar o `IndexedDB`.

Mas infelizmente o seu problema é com a WebView, apenas na Versão `4.4` a `WebView` passou a ser baseada no `Chromium`, para ser exatato, ele utiliza a mesma versão do `Chorme` Ver 30 para `Android`... você pode ler mais a respeito no seguinte link: [WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) ou [Can I Use IndexedDB](http://caniuse.com/#search=IndexedDB)

Então você tem duas opções, continuar com o IndexedDB e atualizar o Android para 4.4+ ou comprar um equipamento mais atualizado.

A sua segunda opção é utilizar o [`SQLite`](https://www.sqlite.org), como acredito que o `IntelXDK` é baseado no `Cordova`, você pode usar o seguinte plugin: [cordova-plugin-sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlite)