# Qual a diferença entre Local Storage, IndexedDB e WebSQL?

Tags: html5, banco-de-dados, front-end, localstorage, indexeddb

Tenho costume de usar o Local Storage para guardar JWT, gostaria de saber a diferença entre o Local Storage, IndexedDB e WebSQL e quando usar um ou outro.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Esqueça WebSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109030/101). Era para ser um banco de dados relacional, mas foi abandonado pelo padrão e hoje só funciona nos navegadores baseados no Chromium, sem receber atenção, pode até ter ficado inseguro.

#### Local Storage

Serve para armazenar dados muito simples, é meio que um cache básico. Por exemplo pode guardar dados que são um pouco mais complexos do que usaria em um *cookie* para posteriormente usar na página que depende dele.

Basicamente ele é uma tabela *hash*, um dicionário com chaves nomeadas através de *strings* e que guarda valores normalmente básicos, nada complexo. Ela é persistida então o dado se mantém de uma sessão para outra a não ser que explicitamente você mande apagar. E obviamente é muito simples usar sua API já que a funcionalidade é limitada. É mais ou menos como persistir um enorme objeto JS nele.

Pode ser dados de configuração e preferências do usuário para usar a página de forma mais interessante.

#### IndexedDb

Pode ser considerado um banco de dados para armazenar bem mais informações, ter muito mais complexidade no que coloca lá, de formas diferentes, com compromissos mais interessantes e de forma mais conveniente para o intuito de armazenar dados diversos. Por exemplo ele permite criar índices para os dados, então dá para acessar de forma eficiente de várias formas. Também pode manipular os dados de forma transacional.

Ele não chega ser um banco de dados completo, principalmente não é relacional, que pode competir com os softwares do tipo que você costuma usar no *backend*, mas pode fazer muita coisa próxima disto. Em geral será usado como um cache mais amplo ou para algo que seja PWA.

Obviamente é um pouco mais complicado usá-lo.

Dá para fazer uma aplicação que depende de um banco de dados no *frontend*, ainda que quase sempre será um pouco exagero fazê-lo.

Não sei se mudou algo, mas fazia pouco sentido o *local storage* ter uma API assíncrona já que lida com poucos dados e de forma simples, já o IndexedDB isso é fundamental e desde o início a API foi pensada assim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).